# Replace directory in a git repo with another existing git repo

Tags: git, github

I have two git repositories.  I wish to replace a directory in the first repository with the second repository, have the second repository act as a submodule, and allow both to keep their history.

How can this be accomplished? Thank you

Comment: Are you just asking how to use git submodules?

Comment: @AD7six  I think more that that.  Both the first repo is existing and has a history which includes the directory that is going to be replaced by the second repo.  I don't care about the history of the files in the deleted directory of the first repo, and suppose I can delete all the files in it and commit their removal, and maybe then add a submodule to it?

Comment: That still sounds exactly like using a submodule. What aspect of that requires clarification? Please update the question

Comment: @user1032531: I think you answered your own question :D try it and come back to this question if you hit any extra issue

Comment: @AD7six  Maybe none.  Let me try a submodule.  Off topic, however, do you feel this is a good use for a submodule since I "own" both?  Reading up, I get mixed messages about whether they are more trouble than they are worth.  Thanks

Comment: @LeGEC  Sounds like a plan.  Thanks for the confirmation.